# TCP messages halt after indeterminate period

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP client that sends a 14 byte String once a second to a TCP server that just prints the string.

Client is an Android app, Server is a simple Java app running on a laptop. Comms are wifi from client to router then ethernet to laptop.

Client connects to server OK and starts sending messages, but after an indeterminate time the server stops receiving the messages.

Looking at the wireshark traffic from the server shows the last message was ACKed by the server but the client clearly never receives the ACK because it retransmits the message and the server sends a DUP ACK. After that no more messages appear until I explicitly close the `socket.outputStream()` on the client at which point the server receives all of the messages and Wireshark shows a TCP frame containing all the missing messages.

NB I am flushing after each message. And TCP_NODELAY has zero effect.

1. Why are the messages suddenly being buffered?
2. What do I can do stop it?

NB the code below is not designed for production use. It is just so I can debug this.

Client:

```
private class SocketSender implements Runnable {

    private final Socket socket = new Socket();

    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting SocketSender");
        toggleButtons(SocketState.Transmitting);
        try {
            startSending();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "", e);
        }
        toggleButtons(SocketState.AwaitingClose);
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping SocketSender");
    }

    private void startSending() throws IOException {
        int counter = 1;
        Log.d(TAG, "Opening Socket to " + HOST_ADDRESS + ":" + HOST_PORT);
        //socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        //socket.setPerformancePreferences(0, 1, 0);
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOST_ADDRESS, HOST_PORT), 3000);
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenedSocket");
        try {
            final OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();
            final PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(stream);
            while (sending) {
                final String message = "Ping pingId=" + counter;
                output.println(message);
                output.flush();
                Log.d(TAG, "Sent message : " + message);
                counter++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sleep interrupted", e);
                }
            }
            output.close();
        } finally {
            //socket.close();
        }
    }

    private void closeSocket() {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Could not close Socket", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
private void readStream() throws IOException {
    final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    final InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    long lastMessage = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (true) {
        final String inputLine = in.readLine();
        long thisMessage = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (inputLine == null) {
            System.out.println("  No more input from : " + socket);
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(format.format(new Date(thisMessage)) + "  '" + inputLine + "' from : " + socket + "  millisSinceLastMsg=" + (thisMessage - lastMessage));
        lastMessage = thisMessage;
    }
    socket.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing 8 different access points and 11 different phone models it seems this is just an issue for the Huawei Y300 when combined with certain access points.

I couldn't determine what about the APs causes things to lock up, so I have just decided to avoid this phone where possible.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that the sender isn't receiving the ACKs. That's a network problem, not a coding problem. It's surprising that the sender didn't fill its send buffer, block, ultimately time out the pending send, and reset the connection.

You might be better off setting a read timeout at the receiver, and closing the connection if it fires. That way the client will get a connection reset and will at least know something's wrong, then it can reconnect or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: The problem with setting a read timeout, is that in the real world application the messages don't come through at predefined/regular times, but arbitrarily, so there no way to distinguish between lack of message and message not being provided.

Comment: Is the reason the client stops sending messages because it has yet to receive an ACK for the final message received by the server?

Comment: I should also point out that this error occurs on 2 high-end wifi access points while it doesn't occur on a mid range and very high-end AP. So it seems to be AP specific, but I don't know what or why.

Comment: The client will eventually fill its send buffer and then block in `send()`. Data is only removed from the send buffer when it has been ACK'd.

Comment: So given that this appears to be a wifi AP issue. What config/settings of the AP should I be looking at to try to ensure higher reliability of message transmission (NB messages are failing with the device only 2m from the AP)